# Ambiguous use of Subscript in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Does anyone know why I get this error?

```
     func parseData(JSONData: Data){
    do{
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONStandard
        if let tracks = readableJSON["tracks"] as? JSONStandard{
            if let items = tracks["items"]{
                for i in 0..<items.count {
                    let item = items[i] as! JSONStandard //Here I get the error: Ambiguous use of 'subscript(_:)'
                    let name = item["name"]
                    names.append(name)
```

Comment: It doesn't know what type `items` is. Don't use `jsonObject(with)`. Use `Codable` with appropriate struct(s)

Comment: What does that mean in my code? Sorry I'm pretty new to swift.

Comment: It's not a huge change in your code, but it does require you to create structs for your data. Refer to [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types). There are also lots of tutorials on the web if you search for "swift codable".  Swift is strongly typed while `jsonObject(with:)` has been around since Objective C so it doesn't return typed objects. That means you have to use a lot of casting to let Swift know what is going on.  By using Codable with structs you have strongly typed data from your json.

Answer (score 0):

Change following

```
    if let items = tracks["items"]
```

To

```
    if let items = tracks["items"] as? [JSONSStandard]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now I get an error that says: Cannot subscript a value of type 'GuestPartyViewController.JSONStandard' (aka 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>') with an argument of type 'Int'